# Guidance for adding Varnish cache to supervisor/gunicorn/nginx setup?

Tags: django, caching, nginx, varnish

I have a DigitalOcean Debian 7 server with 48GB of RAM, running a Django 1.7 app. I would like to add a cache to speed up the app: I'm not expecting hugely high traffic, but there is a large database behind the application, and queries can be quite heavy, even after lots of database optimisation.

I have successfully set the server up as [in this article](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). As I understand the setup there, the Django app is served with gunicorn, and supervisord will restart it automatically if the server restarts. And Nginx sits in front of everything, serving the files at `/static` and `/media`, and pointing to the Django app for files at `/`. (This is how I understand the setup in the article, but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

My question now is how to add Varnish caching to this setup to speed things up.

I've been reading [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-nginx-php-and-varnish-on-ubuntu-12-04) about a related setup, and it seems that my approach should be as follows:

1. Install Varnish
2. Reset nginx to run on port 8080
3. Configure Varnish to run on port 80

Is that the right approach for adding Varnish to this setup?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting Varnish between nginx and gunicorn. This way nginx can stil serve static assets.

I mainly use uWSGI in stead of gunicorn. They have a best practice described here:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example#varnish

Also be aware of the fact that Varnish doesn't cache requests with cookies in them. See: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/09/23/varnish-caching-for-unauthenticated-django-views.html